# Pass a String to another class

Tags: java, string, class

I'm writing an application where I need to get two `String` objects from the GUI to the `nullObject` class.

I'm relatively new to programming, and am trying my best to learn. If you have any tips on how to make this better, I'd be really thankful!

My GUI class:

```
package com.giuly.jsoncreate;

public class GUI {
    private JFrame startFrame;
    private JFrame chkFrame;
    private JFrame osFrame;
    private JFrame appVFrame;

    private JPanel controlPanel;

    private JButton nextPage;
    private JButton cancel;
    private JButton save;

    public GUI() {
        generateGUI();
    }

    public static void main(String[]args) {
        GUI gui = new GUI();
    }

    public void generateGUI() {
        //Creation of the First Frame
        startFrame = new JFrame("JSCON Creator");
        startFrame.setSize(1000, 700);
        startFrame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        startFrame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        //Panel Creation
        controlPanel = new JPanel();
        controlPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        //Button Creation
        cancel = new JButton("Cancel");
        cancel.setSize(100, 100);
        cancel.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });

        nextPage = new JButton("Next");
        nextPage.setSize(100, 100);
        nextPage.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                startFrame.setVisible(false);
                showText();
            }
        });
        startFrame.add(controlPanel);
        startFrame.add(cancel);
        startFrame.add(nextPage);
        startFrame.setVisible(true);
        startFrame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
    }
    public void showText() {
        JFrame textFrame = new JFrame();
        textFrame.setSize(1000, 700);
        textFrame.setTitle("Text");
        textFrame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        JPanel textPanel = new JPanel();

        JLabel titleLabel = new JLabel("Title");
        textPanel.add(titleLabel);
        JLabel descrLabel = new JLabel("Description");

        JTextField tfTitle = new JTextField("",15);
        tfTitle.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        tfTitle.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

        JTextField tfDescr = new JTextField("",30);
        tfDescr.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
        tfDescr.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

        textPanel.add(tfTitle);

        textPanel.add(descrLabel);
        textPanel.add(tfDescr);

        JButton buttonOK = new JButton("OK");
        textPanel.add(buttonOK);
        buttonOK.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String jsonTitle = tfTitle.getText();
                String jsonDescr = tfDescr.getText();
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        textFrame.add(textPanel);
        textFrame.setVisible(true);
}
```

I want to get the Strings `jsonTitle` and `jsonDescr` into another class, so I can store them. In the end I will have some Strings and I need to save them in a JSON file. I need a way to get those two Strings, what advice do you guys have?

Comment: What do you mean by "to the nullObject class"? You haven't explained what class that is at all - but you've included a lot of code, most of which is almost certainly irrelevant. Please read http://tinyurl.com/stack-hints and clarify your question.

Answer (score 1):

Erick is correct with his answer. Just thought I should add additional info. If you declare `jstonTitle` and `jsonDescr` like your other fields using `private` you still will not be able to access these fields from another class. Coding up a getter for the fields along with declaring them at the top of `GUI` should solve your problem. Then just create an instance of `GUI` in your other class and call the method.

```
public String getJsonTitle(){
    return this.jsonTitle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're declaring `jstonTitle` and `jsonDescr` inside the `actionPerformed()` method. That means that as soon as `actionPerformed()` exits you'll lose those variables. You need to declare them in an enclosing context. For example, you could make them fields on the `GUI` class. Still assign them in `actionPerformed()`, but declare them up at the top of `GUI` where you're declaring `startFrame`, `chkFrame`, etc.

That will give you the ability to access those values from anywhere within `GUI`.

Oh, BTW, get rid of `System.exit(0);`. (Have you actually tried to run your program?)